# Upgrading a component requires two reboots

Tags: mfc

I am writing an application which makes an exe from set of msi.
If an msi is getting upgraded, application will uninstall previous version and installs latest. 
My question is, If uninstall and install require reboots  do I need to reboot twice or one reboot is sufficient? Because I need to reduce reboots as much as possible.

Comment: I release new versions of our software via msi all the time. I have never needed a reboot even once. If you are not doing driver stuff, I can't imagine why you would need a reboot.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to answer this simply by trying it?